# Checking values in a boolean array of a KeyBox object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

I create a `KeyBox` class with `boolean[] cells` and `KeyBox` object `box = new KeyBox(new boolean[3])`.
How to check if the `cell` values of the box object are `false`.

My code is:

```java
public class KeyBox {
    static int numberCells = 3;
    boolean[] cells;

    public KeyBox(boolean[] cells) {
        this.cells = cells;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyBox box = new KeyBox(new boolean[numberCells]);
        PutKey.put(box);
    }
}
```

```java
public class PutKey {
    public static void put(KeyBox box) {
        boolean isTrue = Arrays.asList(box.cells).stream().findAny().equals("false");
        System.out.println(isTrue);
    }
}
```

By default `boolean` get `false` value, I am expect that `sout isTrue` will get `true`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to check to see if a *boolean* array contains a specific value.

The first would be to simply traverse the array, setting *isTrue* to *true* when a *false* value is encountered.

```java
boolean isTrue = false;
for (boolean value : box.cells) {
    if (!value) {
        isTrue = true;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(isTrue);
```

If you're looking to utilize a *stream*—as you've used in your code initially—you can use the following.

You'll have to convert the *boolean* array to a *List* of *Boolean* first.

```java
List<Boolean> cells = new ArrayList<>();
for (boolean value : box.cells) cells.add(value);
boolean isTrue = cells.stream().anyMatch(b -> !b);
System.out.println(isTrue);
```